# Should I use Guava Predicate or Java Predicate?

Tags: java, guava, predicate

As far as I understand, Predicates in Guava were created to fill the gap in Java, before Predicates have been introduced to it in Java 8. Now when there is such functionality in Java, does that still make sense to use Guava Predicates? Is there any added value in that?

Comment: No, that's not it. Guava has had predicates loooong before Java 8 was even starting to be formalized. If you use Java 8, you might as well use what Java 8 provides, especially since you can reuse your Guava predicates, if any, using method references anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the opportunity to use Java 8, then "go for it".

Historically, it is true that Guava has defined `Predicate`, or `Function` and other such "functional interfaces" (as they are now called) long before Java 8 was even formalized; and in effect, they are the same.

What is not the same however is that Java 8 brings in syntax which harnesses the power of JSR 292 to its fullest, which is why `Objects::nonNull` is a valid (java.util.function.)`Predicate<Object>`.

So, while Guava "predates" Java 8 in a lot of ways with regards to those interfaces, if you use Java 8, well, use Java 8. Use Java's Function, not Guava's, etc. And if you already have Guava's instances of such interfaces, you can easily reuse them in Java 8; for instance, given a Guava Predicate, turning it into a Java 8 predicate is as easy as:

```
myPredicate::apply
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. One of the ideas in using Predicates in Guava was that you can then interoperate with the rest of its API, such as with Iterables. Isn't that a good reason to still prefer Guava over Java Predicates in some cases? Or does Java provides an alternative in the form of lambda expressions? Thanks.

Comment: Look at how you use `Iterables` today; if you can see an easy replacement with streams, then why not. Of course, don't go and replace everything at once. Use your brains :)

Comment: Yes, of course :) The thing is that currently I am just used to work with Guava as this is what was used in the project that I have been working on lately. Now I am going to start a new project so I guess what I really wanted to ask is whether I'll be able to use "pure Java"  to implement ideas that I was able to implement only in Guava prior to Java 8.

Comment: Then it is a good opportunity to see what Java 8 offers -- and that is a lot :)

Comment: "Yes, we'd like everyone to feel motivated to migrate to the new standard." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/ZRmDJnAq9T0

Comment: @EugeneS as long as you use lambdas and method references you can use methods that accept either.